# Audio setup question and switches

Tags: audio

I have a lot of devices that I would like to connect to my current speakers (or new speakers if needed). The following devices that I would like to connect are:

1. Apple TV (via HD component)
2. Xbox (via HD component)
3. Digital cable box (via hd component)
4. Laptop (via 3.5 mm)
5. Desktop (via 7.1 channel)

I would like to connect all of these devices to one set of speakers. How can i do that? Are there switches I can buy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple switch can work, but with that many devices you will want to probably look at either a mixer (so that you can have more than one device active at once and set levels) or a amplifier/receiver that you can plug multiple devices in and select just one.

Some receivers are getting smart and allow you some basic features of a mixer - but they are not cheap.

You do not have a location in your profile, so I can't really recommend any shops or brands, but my advise would be to go in to a specialist shop or look online and ask lots of questions to make sure you get what you want.

Hopefully I have pointed you in the correct direction, but the fact is that there are thousands of devices and it is hard to pick a specific one for you.

Mixer:

[image]

Receiver

[image]

Comment: note most mixers like the one pictured won't support HDMI audio or 7.1 connections (without splitting them out into individual channels).  but modern receivers can.

Comment: +1 @~quack, agreed - I haven't seen or used one in years and I don't know what's new.. as I said in the post, I am just pointing him in the right direction... does everyone who wants this sort of thing just use amps/receivers now adays then?